# Using a complex pivot_wider to deal with a time series / longitudinal measurement design

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have three variables in my dataset (name, age_group, parents_total). `parents_total` was measured two times. Now, I would like to use`pivot_wider` to keep the `name` and `age_group` but "compute" a new variable with the t2 result of the `parents_total`.

In this example, `age_group` may change. If possible, I would like to compute this "t2" variable if `age_group` remained the same.

[image: dataset]

Related topic:
[pivot_wider issue "Values in `values_from` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58837773/pivot-wider-issue-values-in-values-from-are-not-uniquely-identified-output-w)

["partial" pivot wide in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61511610/partial-pivot-wide-in-r)

Data and codes

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("Arthur Henry Ra", "Laura Fernanda ", 
                              "Gabriel Mistr<e3>o", "Gabriel Augusto", "Felipe Antonio ", "Ana Beatriz de ", 
                              "Laura Fernanda ", "Pedro Henrique ", "Felipe de Melo ", "Gabriel Augusto", 
                              "Seann Nichollas", "Gabriel Prata N", "Henrique Cesar ", "Rizotony Bogach", 
                              "Henrique Cesar ", "Pedro Henrique ", "Jos<e9> Marques Go", "Jo<e3>o Guilherme ", 
                              "Giovanna Marcia", "Jo<e3>o Pedro Silv", "Ana Luisa Santa", "Heitor Faria da", 
                              "Pedro Domencian", "Heitor Faria da", "Jo<e3>o Guilherme ", "Jo<e3>o Pedro Silv", 
                              "Melissa Aguila ", "Raphael Pescuma", "Jos<e9> Marques Go", "Maria Tereza Si", 
                              "Larissa Fernand", "Pedro Cesar Rib", "Pedro Cesar Rib", "Nicollas Manuel", 
                              "Melissa Aguila ", "Matheus Alexand", "Arthur Henry Ra", "Seann Nichollas", 
                              "Lucas de Lucca ", "Matheus Alexand", "Felipe Antonio ", "Giovanna Marcia", 
                              "Gisela Brand<e3>o ", "Felipe de Melo ", "Gabriel Mistr<e3>o", 
                              "Leticia Silva M", "Larissa Fernand", "Nicollas Manuel", "Isabela Carolin", 
                              "Giovanna Marcia", "Isabela Carolin", "Ana Luisa Santa", "Gisela Brand<e3>o ", 
                              "Jo<e3>o Vitor Lope", "Gabriel Augusto", "Vitor Pontes Ra", "Gabriel Augusto", 
                              "Tainara da Silv", "Larissa Fernand", "Ana Beatriz de ", "Vitor Pontes Ra", 
                              "Matheus Alexand", "Gabriel Prata N", "Luis Augusto Sc", "Larissa Fernand", 
                              "Pedro Domencian", "Raphael Pescuma", "Rizotony Bogach", "Maria Tereza Si", 
                              "Lucas de Lucca ", "Jo<e3>o Pedro Silv", "Luis Augusto Sc", "Jo<e3>o Vitor Lope", 
                              "Tainara da Silv", "Leticia Silva M", "Henrique Cesar "), age_group = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                                                5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 
                                                                                                                3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 3L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 
                                                                                                                3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                7L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("[5,6]", 
                                                                                                                                                                        "(6,8]", "(8,10]", "(10,12]", "(12,14]", "(14,16]", "(16,18]", 
                                                                                                                                                                        "(18,Inf]"), class = "factor"), parents_total = c(177, 178, 91, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          128, 138, 146, 185, 177, 97, 79, 167, 160, 96, 160, 138, 165, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          86, 183, 94, 118, 109, 144, 114, 132, 169, 106, 21, 131, 137, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          123, 84, 190, 186, 162, 103, 180, 172, 135, 129, 189, 122, 115, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          122, 66, 96, 151, 95, 179, 196, 122, 182, 112, 147, 133, 125, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          152, 112, 162, 168, 100, 110, 189, 136, 193, 140, 131, 117, 186, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          98, 158, 103, 94, 147, 148, 144, 156)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -76L))
```

Comment: Does this helps `library(dplyr);library(data.table);library(tidyr);library(stringr); df %>% mutate(rn = str_c('parents_total_t', rowid(name, age_group))) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = parents_total)`

Comment: Thank you, @akrun!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(name, age_group) %>%
  mutate(tn = paste0("parents_total_t", row_number())) %>%
  pivot_wider(c(name, age_group), names_from = tn, values_from = parents_total) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 58 x 4
#    name                 age_group parents_total_t1 parents_total_t2
#    <chr>                <fct>                <dbl>            <dbl>
#  1 "Arthur Henry Ra"    (6,8]                  177               NA
#  2 "Laura Fernanda "    (12,14]                178               NA
#  3 "Gabriel Mistr<e3>o" (12,14]                 91               96
#  4 "Gabriel Augusto"    (10,12]                128              112
#  5 "Felipe Antonio "    [5,6]                  138               NA
#  6 "Ana Beatriz de "    (8,10]                 146               NA
#  7 "Laura Fernanda "    (10,12]                185               NA
#  8 "Pedro Henrique "    (12,14]                177               NA
#  9 "Felipe de Melo "    (6,8]                   97               NA
# 10 "Gabriel Augusto"    (8,10]                  79              125
# # ... with 48 more rows
```

Comment: Amazing!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without pivoting.

The pattern of data suggest first to `arrange`

and then `mutate` a new column using `lead`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  arrange(name, parents_total) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(parents_total2 = lead(parents_total),
         parents_total = ifelse(parents_total == last(parents_total), NA, parents_total))
```

```
   name              age_group parents_total parents_total2
   <chr>             <fct>             <dbl>          <dbl>
 1 "Ana Beatriz de " (6,8]               100            146
 2 "Ana Beatriz de " (8,10]               NA             NA
 3 "Ana Luisa Santa" (12,14]             109            112
 4 "Ana Luisa Santa" (14,16]              NA             NA
 5 "Arthur Henry Ra" NA                  172            177
 6 "Arthur Henry Ra" (6,8]                NA             NA
 7 "Felipe Antonio " (6,8]               122            138
 8 "Felipe Antonio " [5,6]                NA             NA
 9 "Felipe de Melo " (8,10]               66             97
10 "Felipe de Melo " (6,8]                NA             NA
# ... with 66 more rows
```

Comment: Woww! Thank you! I did not know the `lead` function